# How to read a KTable using consumer API (Node)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I want to read a Kafka table and streams from a Node JS client.
How can I do that?
I know how to read from a topic but can't find a good example of how to read from a stream or table.

Also, I want to sink a stream from Kafka to Postgres Database.
I know how to sink a topic to a Postgres table.

Comment: The easiest way - you have to materialize your KStream into a topic (since you already can read from a topic). Or get familiar with [Interactive Queries](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html)